# Tessarect implementation JAVA

Tags: eclipse, api, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to implement OCR recognition through Tessarect.
But at the moment I'm stuck with this error.
This is what I've done so far:

- Homebrew tessarect
- Download the API
- Link the Jar with my project (build path > Configure build path > Add external Jar's

But when I compile my code this is the error

> Error opening data file D:/Tess4J/tessdata/eng.traineddata
>   Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
>   Failed loading language 'eng'
>   Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
>   Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.

I've downloaded the eng trained data and I've tried different stuff but I can't figure out how to solve this.

I'm running eclipse in macOS Catalina.

Thanks!

[My situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKQqs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Set your datapath correctly.
Your location D:/Tess4J/tessdata/eng.traineddata is wrong